# How to change sizes of vehicle in Flow simulation?

Tags: python, sumo, flow-project

It seems that we can only create a `stable size` of `vehicles` in `Flow Simulation`. How can we change the size(include `length`, `width` of `car`) of vehicles?

Answer (score 3):

That does not seem to be currently supported, however you can easily change it by adding a `length` parameter to `VehicleParam`'s `add` method, and setting `type_params['length'] = length` in this method. (Also add `'length': length` in the `self.type_parameters[veh_id]` dict if you want to use inflows).